# Does $P(A|B)+P(A|\bar{B}) \neq 1?$

Tags: probability

Well, i had this question in a test yesterday, and question was as follows:
Does $P(A|B)+P(A|\bar{B}) =  1?$
(mark the right answer):
1.sometimes yes and sometimes not.
2.never
3.always

if its (1) then give examples, else prove.
So far i know that is not (3). but i really don't know how to prove (2), and by giving examples to (1) i can't just say "let $P(A|B)=P(A|\bar{B}) = 0.5?$?" what i'm missing? tnx a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer 2. is incorrect since:$$P(A|A)+P(A|\bar{A}) =1+0=1$$
Answer 3. is incorrect since if $A$ and $B$ are independent then: $$P(A|B)+P(A|\bar{B})=P(A)+P(A)=2P(A)$$
so not necessarily $=1$.

Then automatically answer 1. is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

What happens if you take $A=B$?

Answer (score 1):

$P(A|B)+P(A|\overline{B})=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}+\frac{P(A\cap \overline{B})}{P(\overline {B})}$So, this equals to $1\implies $ $$(1-P(B))P(A\cap B)+P(B)(P(A)-P(A\cap B))=P(B)(1-P(B))\\\implies P(A\cap B)(1-2P(B))=P(B)(1-P(A)-P(B))\\\implies P(A\mid B)=\frac{1-P(A)-P(B)}{1-2P(B)}$$ So this is not true in general, but is true if $A=B$, or if $P(A),P(B),P(A\mid B)$ are such that they satisfy the above equation.

Comment: are there any more solutions to that equation apart from $A=B$?