# In what situations is this true: $P(A|B) = 1 - P(A|B^c)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I am working on some software that uses Bayes' rule to find $P(B|A)$

It asks the user to define $P(A|B)$ but it says that $P(A|B^c)$ is optional, if the user chooses not to define it then it sets $P(A|B^c) = 1 - P(A|B)$.

This seems slightly odd to me. Is there a group of cases where $P(A|B^c) = 1 - P(A|B)$ holds true.

Related but does not answer: [Does $P(A\mid B)$ determine $P(A\mid \bar{B})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4416765/1043577)

Related: [Does $P(A|B)+P(A|\bar{B}) \neq 1?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1146319/1043577)

Comment: If A is empty the statement says $1=0.$

Comment: To me, the more *natural* choice of a default expression for $P(A\mid B^c)$ would be $P(A\mid B^c)=P(A\mid B)$ (i.e., the default assumption is that $A,B$ are independent). Of course, in a context that is explicitly "aware" of Bayes rule, it would be wiser to make $P(A\mid B^c)$ a mandatory input.

Comment: The question means $P(A|B)=P(A^c|B^c)$, so for example is the probability of owning a car knowing that you live in New York equal to the probability of not owning a car knowing that you don't live in New York? A very unlikely coincidence!

Comment: $P(A|B^c) = 1 - P(A|B)$ holds in following two cases: (1) $A=B^c$ and (2) $A=B$. It would be cool if these were only cases.

Comment: @FirstNameLastName It can be true by chance. Take a group of 10 men and 5 women, of which 2 men and 4 women are married. Take a random person in the group and let A = the person is married and B = the person is a woman. Of course the result becomes false if 3 men are married instead of 2.

Comment: @Gribouillis : right, I was also suspecting some special cases. Thanks for example

Comment: Harvs : I believe @Gribouillis gave answer to your question in title: it can somewhat unlikely happen. The *related* questions are perhaps not to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Does $P(A|B)+P(A|\bar{B}) \neq 1?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146319/does-pabpa-barb-neq-1)

as said in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1146329/1043577) by @drhab

$P(A|A)+P(A|A¯)=1+0=1$

So if $P(A)=P(B)$

Comment: I agree this is a duplicate ... only ... I was confused by two notations $X¯$ and $X^c$ to mean the same: $not X$